# Swift "timer" variable

Tags: ios, swift, timer, thread-safety

I need multithread safe `Int` variable in Swift that could be incremented or decremented in different threads. Moreover, this variable must be decremented by 1 every second and notify (by block or selector) when it has zero value.

What is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding apple swift block you needn't think about it.

> One of the primary reasons to choose value types over reference types
>   is the ability to more easily reason about your code. If you always
>   get a unique, copied instance, you can trust that no other part of
>   your app is changing the data under the covers. This is especially
>   helpful in multi-threaded environments where a different thread could
>   alter your data out from under you. This can create nasty bugs that
>   are extremely hard to debug.

https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10

[Int is a value type](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int). So, you can use it in several threads without worries.